RevenueCat - customerInfo.activeSubscriptions always returns value
This is a production bug where users who have previously been subscribed still have access to all Pro features due to customerInfo.activeSubscriptions returning all productIdentifiers of previous subscriptions.
Also customerInfo.entitlements always returns value.
I have added
print("ENTITLEMENTS \(customerInfo.entitlements)")
                        
print("ACTIVE SUBS \(customerInfo.activeSubscriptions)")

This returns

ENTITLEMENTS ["pro": <EntitlementInfo: "
ACTIVE SUBS ["com.appname.com.promonthly", "com.appname.com.proyearly"]

I have tried using
customerInfo.entitlements.active

But I get the same result.
I have also tried removing cached info with
    Purchases.shared.invalidateCustomerInfoCache()

Also when opening Debug > StoreKit, not transactions are show.
This is the code to verify the subscription status.
func verifyIAPReceipt() {
    
    Purchases.shared.invalidateCustomerInfoCache()
   
    Purchases.shared.getCustomerInfo { (customerInfo, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let customerInfo = customerInfo {
                
                if customerInfo.entitlements.active.isEmpty {
                    
                    print("ENTITLEMENTS IS EMPTY") <-- This is not executed

                    self.unsubscribe()

                } else {
                        
                        print("ENTITLEMENTS IS NOT EMPTY") <-- Executed

                    print("ENTITLEMENTS \(customerInfo.entitlements)")
                    print("ACTIVE SUBS \(customerInfo.activeSubscriptions)")

                    if customerInfo.activeSubscriptions.isEmpty == false {
                        print("Active Subscriptions is NOT empty") <-- Executed
                        
                        for s in customerInfo.activeSubscriptions  {
                            if s == "com.app.come.promonthly" || s == "com.app.com.proyearly"  {
                                subscribe() <-- Executed Unlocks features
                            } 
                        }
                    } else if customerInfo.activeSubscriptions.isEmpty == true {
                        print("Active Subscriptions are empty")
                        self.unsubscribe()
                    } else {
                        print("Active Subscription and profile is subscribed")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            
        } else {
            print("ERROR GETTING CUSTOMER INFO TO VERIFY RECEIPTS")
        }
    }
}

When using fetchPolicy: .fetchCurrent it is returning active subscriptions
    Purchases.shared.getCustomerInfo(fetchPolicy: .fetchCurrent, completion: { (customerInfo, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("FETCH POLICY ERROR:\(error)")
        }
        
        if customerInfo != nil {
            print("FETCH POLICY ACTIVE SUBSCRIPTIONS:\(customerInfo!.activeSubscriptions)")
            print("FETCH POLICY ACTIVE ENTITLEMENTS:\(customerInfo!.entitlements)")
            print("FETCH POLICY ACTIVE ALL PURCHASED PRODUCT ID'S:\(customerInfo!.allPurchasedProductIdentifiers)")
        }
    })

Output

FETCH POLICY ACTIVE ENTITLEMENTS:["pro": <EntitlementInfo: "


FETCH POLICY ACTIVE ENTITLEMENTS:<RCEntitlementInfos: self.all=[:],


self.active=[:],self.verification=VerificationResult.notRequested>


FETCH POLICY ACTIVE ALL PURCHASED PRODUCT
ID'S:["com.appname.com.promonthly", "com.appname.com.proyearly"]

This is the subscribe code
func subscribe() {

print("Subscribe")


//Revenue Cat

if let packages = offering?.availablePackages {
    for p in packages {
        if p.storeProduct.productIdentifier == selectedproductbundle {
                            
            Purchases.shared.purchase(package: p) { (transaction, customerInfo, error, userCancelled) in
                
                print("PURCHASE")
                
                if userCancelled {
                    print("User cancelled purchase")
                    return
                }
                
                if let err = error {
                    
                    if let error = error as? RevenueCat.ErrorCode {
                        print(error.errorCode)
                        print("ERROR: \(error.errorUserInfo)")
                        
                        switch error {
                        case .purchaseNotAllowedError:
                            errorDescription = "Purchases not allowed on this device."
                            showError.toggle()
                            
                        case .purchaseInvalidError:
                            errorDescription = "Purchase invalid, check payment source."
                            
                        default: break
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                } else if customerInfo?.activeSubscriptions.isEmpty == false {
                    print("Unlocked Pro ")
                    
                    // Update profile
                    print("Customer INFO: \(customerInfo!)")
                    
                    print("Entitlements: \(customerInfo!.entitlements.all)") 
                    
                    if customerInfo != nil {
                        for s in customerInfo!.activeSubscriptions {
                            if s == "com.appname.com.promonthly" || s == "com.appname.com.proyearly"  {
                                subscribeToPro()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("PURCHASE WITH: \(String(describing: transaction?.productIdentifier)) && \(String(describing: customerInfo?.activeSubscriptions.count))")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

I have tested via simulator and on device.

Try fetchPolicy: .fetchCurrent on calling getCustomerInfo() to verify if it's really not the cache issue

JFYI: https://community.revenuecat.com/sdks-51/sync-issues-with-customerinfo-after-subscription-expiration-3546?postid=11761#post11761

@Toru Thank you for your response, It is returning active subscriptions. This is also for production users, they after cancelling their subscription they still have access to all pro features.

Just to confirm, do you have Entitlement configured in RevenueCat? I'm wondering that even all is empty

@Toru I do have entitlements in RevenueCat, Entitlements > Product ("pro") > product identifier ("com.appname.com.promonthly").

Assuming you have your entitlements configured correctly in the RevenueCat dashboard, they should be always returning correct data.
One thing that have cought my eye in your code is that you are trying to call the .active property on entitlements object.
When you take a loot at the implementation of that property you will see the following:
@objc var active: [String: EntitlementInfo] {
    return self.activeInAnyEnvironment
}

Which means that any user that was previously part of the TestFlight group and was able to do any purchase in the sandbox, could still be granted that entitlement.
This is not safe approach if you really want to support just the customers that have actually purchased the subscription.
To solution here is to use the activeInCurrentEnvironment exclusively - instead of active aka activeInAnyEnvironment. Especially in production.
In our app, simply for our own convenience when developing the app, we have introduced the following extension.
extension EntitlementInfos {
    /// Returns activeInAnyEnvironment for TestFlight and DEBUG build and activeInCurrentEnvironment for AppStore version.
    var activeForConfig: [String: EntitlementInfo] {
        switch Distribution.current {
        case .testFlight, .debug: activeInAnyEnvironment
        case .appStore: activeInCurrentEnvironment
        }
    }
}

The Distribution.current value is determined based on the compiler flags and AppStore receipt data.


If a user has subscribed to the app but then unsubscribed, the following code still executes `subscribe()'

Although it's unclear what unsubscribe() and subscribe() do in the code, let's say you want unsubscribe() to be executed when a user no longer has access to the subscription, then it seems your condition check is wrong.
if !customerInfo.entitlements.active.isEmpty {
    print("ENTITLEMENTS IS EMPTY") <-- This is not executed
    self.unsubscribe()
} else {
    print("ENTITLEMENTS IS NOT EMPTY") <-- Executed
    //...
    subscribe() <-- Executed Unlocks features
}

The above code should look like:
if customerInfo.entitlements.active.isEmpty {
    // User no longer has any active subscription
    unsubscribe()
} else {
    subscribe()
}

I'm not sure why customerInfo.activeSubscriptions still returns values even after the subscription is expired though...

It seems entitlements had the wrong productidentifier in RevenueCat. Now the code returns entitlements, however the issue still remains that a user who is not subscribed is getting entitlements and active subscriptions.

"Also when opening Debug > StoreKit, not transactions are show." Are you doing StoreKit Testing in Xcode? I'm wondering if RevenueCat can work with StoreKit Testing in the first place since they probably care about only purchases that happen in real environments or at least sandbox. You better watch the RevenueCat dashboard if the user is really unsubscribed (not only canceled as there's a gap between canceled and expired)

It seems StoreKit Testing can work with RevenueCat but there are many things to do. Did you do all these? https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/test-and-launch/sandbox/apple-app-store#ios-14-only-testing-on-the-simulator
